# Unable to make connection between JIRA and Python

Tags: python, authentication, jira-cli

I'm trying to connect to Jira using python, but my python applications gets stopped after running for almost 1-2 minutes long. Basically it shows: "python.exe has stopped working"

```
My code is as below:

#import libraries
from jira import JIRA    
from jira.exceptions import JIRAError    
import sys    
options = {'server': 'https://sipcg.atlassian.net'}    

try:    
    print("start!")    
    jira = JIRA(options=options, auth=('xyz', 'xyz'))    
except JIRAError as e:    
    if e.status_code == 401:    
        print ("Login to JIRA failed. Check your username and password")    
print ("done!")    

#Please help me in order to connect using jiracli    
#Note: ignore the python indentation attached here
```